# How to show Turn Restriction data from OS MasterMap Highways on the map?

Tags: qgis, gml, os-mastermap

I want to obtain the location and details of all turn restrictions from the OS MasterMap Highway Network datasets I have.

I tried loading the *Turn Restriction* dataset into QGIS but it does not read the location of the features, as the dataset itself does not contain any geometry.

I know that all *Turn Restriction* features are [related by GML-ID to the features in the *Road Link* dataset](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/technical-specifications/os-mastermap-highways-network-routing-and-asset-management-technical-specification.pdf#page=26), but I was told that this could not be done within QGIS as the software does not understand the links in the data.

---

I tried translating both datasets from GZ format to SHP using Astun Technology Loader, hoping the *Turn Restriction* output would contain geometry, but it failed, exporting only a DBF file (see below). So I guess translating to SHP won't help?

[image]

[image]

---

So How can I link those two datasets and **get the turn restriction shown on the map in QGIS**? Preferably methods without much coding?

Comment: please don't use pictures of text in your questions - it is almost impossible to read.

Comment: What about using Loader to add the data to PostGIS which can handle the output? You might need to use the gmlas driver in ogr to get the links out

Comment: The DBF file should be a format you can open as a table. Does it have a shared attribute with features in the road-link data set?

Comment: @IanTurton How exactly do I use the gmlas driver in ogr? Is there any tutorial online that I can follow? Thanks.